# how to check item already exits in sqlite objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

This the my code

```
NSString *query1 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from table name where item_name=%@",trimmedString];
//   [self.dbManager executeQuery:query1];

//  -(void)runQuery:(const char *)query isQueryExecutable:(BOOL)queryExecutable


NSLog(@"q1--%@",query1);
BOOL recordExist = [self.dbManager recordExistOrNot:query1];

NSLog(@"------%d",recordExist);
if (!recordExist)
{


    NSString *query;
  if (self.recordIDToEdit == -1) {
    query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into c values(null,'%@','%d','%d',%d)",item_name.text,a,p,c];

    NSLog(@"query---%@",query);
 }


    // Execute the query.
    [self.dbManager executeQuery:query];

    // If the query was successfully executed then pop the view controller.
    if (self.dbManager.affectedRows != 0) {
        NSLog(@"Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = %d", self.dbManager.affectedRows);

      //  UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:Nil message:@"Successfully Added to The Cart" delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:Nil, nil];
     //   [alert show];
        [self loadData];
               }

    else{
        NSLog(@"Could not execute the query.");

             }
}
else
{

    NSLog(@"item already exits....");
}

- (BOOL)recordExistOrNot:(NSString *)query1{
    sqlite3 *sqlite3Database;
        NSString *databasePath = [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    BOOL recordExist=NO;
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &sqlite3Database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
      //  sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3Database,[query1 UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                recordExist=YES;
            }
            else
            {
                //////NSLog(@"%s,",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
            sqlite3_close(sqlite3Database);
        }
    }
    return recordExist;
}
```

actually i want to be check string value in the table like "select * from table name where item_name=tea"
but this code is checking integer value  but i want check string value.please help me

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the single quotes in you select statement. first line.

```
NSString *query1 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from table name where item_name=%@",trimmedString];
```

to

```
NSString *query1 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from table name where item_name='%@'",trimmedString];
```

Comment: You should never use `stringWithFormat` to build your queries. Do it properly by binding values to a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

i'll assume that item_name is unique then you might be better served with doing insert or ignore.

i.e.

insert or ignore into tablename (item_name) values ('something')

thsi will ignore doing the insert if that value for your key exists

Comment: Terrible idea.  What's wrong with a `SELECT COUNT()`?

Comment: well now youve got extra overhead going back to db twice.  also i should really assume by the rudimentary question that there probably isnt any constraints on the column and simply counting the values then inserting based on that result would potentially end up with duplicates.

Comment: You assume there are no constraints but also assume `item_name` is unique?  Doing a simple count allows the code to decide if it item exists based on the number (probably `== 1`, but it could `> 1` if required).

Comment: you must not understand what he's trying to do there ... if (!recordExist) { } .. and if with your simple count that condition is "true" then another record is inserted in the meantime?

Comment: you feel challenged bro?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I guess you have run out of technical arguments and are reverting to obtuse nonsense instead?

Comment: Actually I understand what you mean with "another record is inserted in the meantime?".  This is a good point for a multi-threaded environment and I agree that it's the best approach.  I wish you had made this clearer in your answer.  If you do I will revert my downvote and delete my comments.